# Magento 2 Multi store with Multi website - Product URL not SEO friendly

Tags: url, magento2, magento-2.3, multistore

I have set up a multi-store website with multi-domain as www.domain-one.com for US and www.domain.two.com for GERMANY. The purpose is to set a different currency set up as per the websites. I am using the same root category for both the stores.

Everything working fine, except the URL of products is not friendly for the 2nd website. Like below,

www.domain-one.com = Product A => www.domain-one.com/product-a.html
www.domain-two.com = Product A =>  www.domain-two.com/catalog/product/view/id/11/s/product-a/category/24/

- How can I resolve this issue?
- Is there any other issue that will be raised for the above architecture with multi-store with multi-domain?

Comment: Please have a look to this link
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/252140/seo-url-not-properly-multiwebsite-magento2

Comment: @RahulBarot should I use a module to fix this issue? 
the above link module is showing as deprecated and redirecting to another link.
Is this a default problem in Magento?